# Spring passing a map as request param

Tags: java, ajax, spring, post, httprequest

I want to pass a map object as a parameter to a spring controller.

My ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/create',
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            data : JSON.stringify({
                pk : 111,
                params : {
                    param1 : 'someValue',
                    param2 : 'anotherValue'
                }
            })
        });
```

My request handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody CrudActionResponse postCreate(HttpSession session,
        @RequestParam(value = "params") Map<String, String> values, Integer pk)
{
    ...
}
```

But everytime I get following exception:

```
 org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Map parameter 'params' is not present
```

Comment: You seem to want to send JSON content. Use `@RequestBody` with the appropriate data type.

Comment: First I tried to send it url encoded which also didn´t work.

Comment: If you're going to send JSON, send it in the body. That's what I was trying to say.

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: Just look it up, you'll find tons.